# What is the Philips screw naming convention (Mn)? What is 2 in M2?

Tags: screws, fastener, screwdriver

I want to order screws like the one I have. The diameter of the threaded portion is 2mm. The length of the threaded portion is 8mm.

The screws are listed as Mn (where n is 1.6,2,2.5...) on various sites. The length parameter is also specified.

I have a feeling that the n represent the diameter of the threaded portion
however even after having searched a lot I found no document that explicitly states this.
Some documents state diameter=M2. So M2 relates to the diameter. But 2 could be in mm, 1/10 of an inch or it could be like shoe size where the number is not a dimension in itself but simply represents one of the many standard sizes.

Side note: I wonder why something as basic as this is not documented clearly. Specs generally go into excruciating detail which includes the naming convention. Where should I have looked for the meaning of this convention? I have gone through ISO-7045 but even it does not state what the n in Mn means.

Comment: So far as I know, the metric thread designations are not associated with American businessman [Henry F Phillips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_F._Phillips), inventor of the crosshead screwdriver named after him.

Comment: If you were searching for information based on the head type, that's why you couldn't find anything. It's unrelated.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place because Philips has little to do with it. This is all documented on the Screw and related Wikipedia pages, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_metric_screw_thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"M" screws are all metric, by standard. The number following the M is the outer diameter of the screw threads, in millimeters, so an M4 screw's threads have an outer diameter of 4mm.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_metric_screw_thread) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about a ***machine* screw**, with orderly threads like a bolt, rather than a metal or wood screw, with a coarser rougher thread that is usually not consistent.

There are a lot of parameters on a machine screw.  The key is to divide and conquer!

### Diameter and thread pitch

These are a matched set (in imperial units) so take them together.  Diameter is the *optimum unthreaded* diameter of the bolt, i.e. The size of the hole the bolt is meant to fit. This will be in mm (M4, M12) or fractions of an inch (1/2) or rod numbers (#4, #6, #8, #10) for sizes below 1/4".

Thread pitch is the fineness of the thread, measured in millimeters between threads (1.25) or threads per inch (20).

They come in *generally* standard pairs, like M4-0.70, M12-1.25, #8-32 or 1/2-20.

### Bolt length

This is measured from the surface that is clamped.  A 50mm bolt length does not include the head unless it's a countersunk type.

### Bolt head type

You have countersunk bolts... Carriage and elevator types... Domed head... Squared-off head... Square, hex or torx head where the outside of the head is the drive mechanism.  And several varieties of each.

### Drive type

Slotted, Phillips, socket head (which uses a hex key to turn), Torx, Robertson, you name it.   In most cases you can afford to use a different head type if you can't find an exact match.  In fact, it's usually a win to get away from the inferior slotted and Phillips types.